# Change the decimal format in XSL

Tags: xslt, format

I have a UnitPrice tag that I want the format to be to the hundredth. So if a number comes in as 0.9. Then it should automatically convert it to 0.90. I've tried it using format and it's not working as intended.

```
Original Tag:
<RetailPrice>
    <xsl:value-of select="UnitPrice"/>
</RetailPrice>

Attempted:
I changed the value of to this: 
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(UnitPrice, '0.00')"/>
```

Is there anything else I can do.

Comment: Even after me adding the value it's still coming as 0.9

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="format-number((./col1 * 100) div 100,'0.00')"/>   Can you check this syntax, it works for me.

Comment: can you provide sample input?, as <xsl:value-of select="format-number(UnitPrice, '0.00')"/>

should produce 0.90 if UnitPrice=0.9